# facebook application -> on my website?

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

Basically, when someone visits X page on my website, I want there to be a "content blocker" which shows a popup asking them to Allow/Deny my facebook application.

If they Allow it, it removes the content blocker and shows the content and never shows the content blocker again if they are logged in to facebook as they have already allowed my application.

If they deny it, it removes the content blocker and shows the content but it will always show the content blocker if they are logged in to facebook and not allowed my application.

I basically want it to work like this:

```
http://tyler.tc/FBLike/
```

But instead of it showing a box with Like in it, I want it to contain my application - which I want to look something like this:

```
http://i56.tinypic.com/vi1xzc.jpg
```

Is there any way I can do this?

I would really appreciate feedback as I'm new to Facebook developing.

Regards.

Comment: Yes you can, accidently voted your comment up. fml.

Comment: sorry then! I deleted my question so as not to confuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Facebook Graph API, there is some documentation for how to do that dialog [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication).  Basically, you can create an `iframe` with its source set to this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&type=user_agent&display=popup
```

Set `client_id` to your application ID and `redirect_uri` to the URL of a server-side handler that can retrieve a user's auth token.